# How do I pass parameters to my docker image when running on Synoogy NAS

Tags: docker, synology

So when launching my image through the gui Synlogy is doing the equivalent of

```
 docker run img
```

but I need it do pass an extra -r argument to the entrypoint

```
 docker run img -r
```

How do I do that ?

I can see how to pass environment variables but not arguments to my entrypoint.

[image]

Comment: can you show the base image?

Comment: You can add commands under in the command text box on the advanced settings environment variables execution command section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you originally launch there is an additional section on the *Environment* tab called *Execution Command* where you can add the command arguments

This only available when launch and image not when you modify a container. So if you need to run the same image with different arguments you launch as multiple containers.

[image]

Comment: "This only available when launch and image not when you modify a container."
 - THANK YOU!